# Passing parameters in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

Hi Every one I have a report contains 2 command objects.But as per my requirement i need to pass one query columns as parameters to another query. I have max time and min time in one query.It should passed as from time and to time parameters to another query

where from time =(min time of 2nd query) and to time =(max time of 2nd query).

How can we do this,any other way like sub reports.Any ideas would be appreciated .Please suggest me

Comment: your requirement is confusing.. what are you trying to perform? are you trying to link two command objects in a single report?

Comment: Hi I have a query in my report having 2 fields fromtime and to time .And i need to pass this fields as parameters to another query. Below is the where condition for 2nd query.                       where from time =(fromtime field of 1st query) and to time =(totime field of 1st query).

Answer (score 0):

One thing you should be clear is crystal reports will create only one query in a report.  If you wish to pass the parameters then I would suggest you to use subreport and then pass the paramter using the linking option in sub report.